# I can't connect to my wireless router even though i was able to do that few days ago. I get errors about duplicate IPv6

Tags: wireless, ipv6, duplicate

```
Feb 11 18:09:12 olga-K54C NetworkManager[5191]: <info> Activation (wlan0) starting connection 'corpse'
Feb 11 18:09:12 olga-K54C NetworkManager[5191]: <info> (wlan0): device state change: disconnected -> prepare (reason 'none') [30 40 0]
Feb 11 18:09:12 olga-K54C NetworkManager[5191]: <info> Activation (wlan0) Stage 1 of 5 (Device Prepare) scheduled...
Feb 11 18:09:12 olga-K54C NetworkManager[5191]: <info> Activation (wlan0) Stage 1 of 5 (Device Prepare) started...
Feb 11 18:09:12 olga-K54C NetworkManager[5191]: <info> Activation (wlan0) Stage 2 of 5 (Device Configure) scheduled...
Feb 11 18:09:12 olga-K54C NetworkManager[5191]: <info> Activation (wlan0) Stage 1 of 5 (Device Prepare) complete.
Feb 11 18:09:12 olga-K54C NetworkManager[5191]: <info> Activation (wlan0) Stage 2 of 5 (Device Configure) starting...
Feb 11 18:09:12 olga-K54C NetworkManager[5191]: <info> (wlan0): device state change: prepare -> config (reason 'none') [40 50 0]
Feb 11 18:09:12 olga-K54C NetworkManager[5191]: <info> Activation (wlan0/wireless): access point 'corpse' has security, but secrets are required.
Feb 11 18:09:12 olga-K54C NetworkManager[5191]: <info> (wlan0): device state change: config -> need-auth (reason 'none') [50 60 0]
Feb 11 18:09:12 olga-K54C NetworkManager[5191]: <info> Activation (wlan0) Stage 2 of 5 (Device Configure) complete.
Feb 11 18:09:12 olga-K54C NetworkManager[5191]: <info> Activation (wlan0) Stage 1 of 5 (Device Prepare) scheduled...
Feb 11 18:09:12 olga-K54C NetworkManager[5191]: <info> Activation (wlan0) Stage 1 of 5 (Device Prepare) started...
Feb 11 18:09:12 olga-K54C NetworkManager[5191]: <info> (wlan0): device state change: need-auth -> prepare (reason 'none') [60 40 0]
Feb 11 18:09:12 olga-K54C NetworkManager[5191]: <info> Activation (wlan0) Stage 2 of 5 (Device Configure) scheduled...
Feb 11 18:09:12 olga-K54C NetworkManager[5191]: <info> Activation (wlan0) Stage 1 of 5 (Device Prepare) complete.
Feb 11 18:09:12 olga-K54C NetworkManager[5191]: <info> Activation (wlan0) Stage 2 of 5 (Device Configure) starting...
Feb 11 18:09:12 olga-K54C NetworkManager[5191]: <info> (wlan0): device state change: prepare -> config (reason 'none') [40 50 0]
Feb 11 18:09:12 olga-K54C NetworkManager[5191]: <info> Activation (wlan0/wireless): connection 'corpse' has security, and secrets exist.  No new secrets needed.
Feb 11 18:09:12 olga-K54C NetworkManager[5191]: <info> Config: added 'ssid' value 'corpse'
Feb 11 18:09:12 olga-K54C NetworkManager[5191]: <info> Config: added 'scan_ssid' value '1'
Feb 11 18:09:12 olga-K54C NetworkManager[5191]: <info> Config: added 'key_mgmt' value 'WPA-PSK'
Feb 11 18:09:12 olga-K54C NetworkManager[5191]: <info> Config: added 'psk' value '<omitted>'
Feb 11 18:09:12 olga-K54C NetworkManager[5191]: <info> Activation (wlan0) Stage 2 of 5 (Device Configure) complete.
Feb 11 18:09:12 olga-K54C NetworkManager[5191]: <info> Config: set interface ap_scan to 1
Feb 11 18:09:13 olga-K54C NetworkManager[5191]: <info> (wlan0): supplicant interface state: disconnected -> scanning
Feb 11 18:09:19 olga-K54C wpa_supplicant[902]: Trying to authenticate with 14:da:e9:ba:ba:a4 (SSID='corpse' freq=2412 MHz)
Feb 11 18:09:19 olga-K54C NetworkManager[5191]: <info> (wlan0): supplicant interface state: scanning -> authenticating
Feb 11 18:09:19 olga-K54C kernel: [ 3178.022135] wlan0: authenticate with 14:da:e9:ba:ba:a4 (try 1)
Feb 11 18:09:19 olga-K54C kernel: [ 3178.024310] wlan0: authenticated
Feb 11 18:09:19 olga-K54C wpa_supplicant[902]: Trying to associate with 14:da:e9:ba:ba:a4 (SSID='corpse' freq=2412 MHz)
Feb 11 18:09:19 olga-K54C NetworkManager[5191]: <info> (wlan0): supplicant interface state: authenticating -> associating
Feb 11 18:09:19 olga-K54C kernel: [ 3178.043509] wlan0: associate with 14:da:e9:ba:ba:a4 (try 1)
Feb 11 18:09:19 olga-K54C wpa_supplicant[902]: Associated with 14:da:e9:ba:ba:a4
Feb 11 18:09:19 olga-K54C kernel: [ 3178.047714] wlan0: RX ReassocResp from 14:da:e9:ba:ba:a4 (capab=0x411 status=0 aid=2)
Feb 11 18:09:19 olga-K54C kernel: [ 3178.047726] wlan0: associated
Feb 11 18:09:19 olga-K54C kernel: [ 3178.048373] cfg80211: Calling CRDA for country: RU
Feb 11 18:09:19 olga-K54C NetworkManager[5191]: <info> (wlan0): supplicant interface state: associating -> associated
Feb 11 18:09:19 olga-K54C kernel: [ 3178.053443] cfg80211: Updating information on frequency 2412 MHz for a 20 MHz width channel with regulatory rule:
Feb 11 18:09:19 olga-K54C kernel: [ 3178.053449] cfg80211: 2402000 KHz - 2482000 KHz @  KHz), (N/A mBi, 2000 mBm)
Feb 11 18:09:19 olga-K54C kernel: [ 3178.053452] cfg80211: Updating information on frequency 2417 MHz for a 20 MHz width channel with regulatory rule:
Feb 11 18:09:19 olga-K54C kernel: [ 3178.053455] cfg80211: 2402000 KHz - 2482000 KHz @  KHz), (N/A mBi, 2000 mBm)
Feb 11 18:09:19 olga-K54C kernel: [ 3178.053458] cfg80211: Updating information on frequency 2422 MHz for a 20 MHz width channel with regulatory rule:
Feb 11 18:09:19 olga-K54C kernel: [ 3178.053462] cfg80211: 2402000 KHz - 2482000 KHz @  KHz), (N/A mBi, 2000 mBm)
Feb 11 18:09:19 olga-K54C kernel: [ 3178.053464] cfg80211: Updating information on frequency 2427 MHz for a 20 MHz width channel with regulatory rule:
Feb 11 18:09:19 olga-K54C kernel: [ 3178.053468] cfg80211: 2402000 KHz - 2482000 KHz @  KHz), (N/A mBi, 2000 mBm)
Feb 11 18:09:19 olga-K54C kernel: [ 3178.053470] cfg80211: Updating information on frequency 2432 MHz for a 20 MHz width channel with regulatory rule:
Feb 11 18:09:19 olga-K54C kernel: [ 3178.053474] cfg80211: 2402000 KHz - 2482000 KHz @  KHz), (N/A mBi, 2000 mBm)
Feb 11 18:09:19 olga-K54C kernel: [ 3178.053477] cfg80211: Updating information on frequency 2437 MHz for a 20 MHz width channel with regulatory rule:
Feb 11 18:09:19 olga-K54C kernel: [ 3178.053480] cfg80211: 2402000 KHz - 2482000 KHz @  KHz), (N/A mBi, 2000 mBm)
Feb 11 18:09:19 olga-K54C kernel: [ 3178.053483] cfg80211: Updating information on frequency 2442 MHz for a 20 MHz width channel with regulatory rule:
Feb 11 18:09:19 olga-K54C kernel: [ 3178.053486] cfg80211: 2402000 KHz - 2482000 KHz @  KHz), (N/A mBi, 2000 mBm)
Feb 11 18:09:19 olga-K54C kernel: [ 3178.053489] cfg80211: Updating information on frequency 2447 MHz for a 20 MHz width channel with regulatory rule:
Feb 11 18:09:19 olga-K54C kernel: [ 3178.053492] cfg80211: 2402000 KHz - 2482000 KHz @  KHz), (N/A mBi, 2000 mBm)
Feb 11 18:09:19 olga-K54C kernel: [ 3178.053495] cfg80211: Updating information on frequency 2452 MHz for a 20 MHz width channel with regulatory rule:
Feb 11 18:09:19 olga-K54C kernel: [ 3178.053498] cfg80211: 2402000 KHz - 2482000 KHz @  KHz), (N/A mBi, 2000 mBm)
F    eb 11 18:09:19 olga-K54C kernel: [ 3178.053501] cfg80211: Updating information on frequency 2457 MHz for a 20 MHz width channel with regulatory rule:
Feb 11 18:09:19 olga-K54C kernel: [ 3178.053504] cfg80211: 2402000 KHz - 2482000 KHz @  KHz), (N/A mBi, 2000 mBm)
Feb 11 18:09:19 olga-K54C kernel: [ 3178.053507] cfg80211: Updating information on frequency 2462 MHz for a 20 MHz width channel with regulatory rule:
Feb 11 18:09:19 olga-K54C kernel: [ 3178.053510] cfg80211: 2402000 KHz - 2482000 KHz @  KHz), (N/A mBi, 2000 mBm)
Feb 11 18:09:19 olga-K54C kernel: [ 3178.053513] cfg80211: Updating information on frequency 2467 MHz for a 20 MHz width channel with regulatory rule:
Feb 11 18:09:19 olga-K54C kernel: [ 3178.053516] cfg80211: 2402000 KHz - 2482000 KHz @  KHz), (N/A mBi, 2000 mBm)
Feb 11 18:09:19 olga-K54C kernel: [ 3178.053519] cfg80211: Updating information on frequency 2472 MHz for a 20 MHz width channel with regulatory rule:
Feb 11 18:09:19 olga-K54C kernel: [ 3178.053523] cfg80211: 2402000 KHz - 2482000 KHz @  KHz), (N/A mBi, 2000 mBm)
Feb 11 18:09:19 olga-K54C kernel: [ 3178.053525] cfg80211: Disabling freq 2484 MHz
Feb 11 18:09:19 olga-K54C kernel: [ 3178.053531] cfg80211: Regulatory domain changed to country: RU
Feb 11 18:09:19 olga-K54C kernel: [ 3178.053533] cfg80211:     (start_freq - end_freq @ bandwidth), (max_antenna_gain, max_eirp)
Feb 11 18:09:19 olga-K54C kernel: [ 3178.053537] cfg80211:     (2402000 KHz - 2482000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm)
Feb 11 18:09:19 olga-K54C kernel: [ 3178.053540] cfg80211:     (5735000 KHz - 5835000 KHz @ 20000 KHz), (N/A, 3000 mBm)
Feb 11 18:09:20 olga-K54C NetworkManager[5191]: <info> (wlan0): supplicant interface state: associated -> 4-way handshake
Feb 11 18:09:20 olga-K54C wpa_supplicant[902]: WPA: Key negotiation completed with 14:da:e9:ba:ba:a4 [PTK=TKIP GTK=TKIP]
Feb 11 18:09:20 olga-K54C wpa_supplicant[902]: CTRL-EVENT-CONNECTED - Connection to 14:da:e9:ba:ba:a4 completed (reauth) [id=0 id_str=]
Feb 11 18:09:20 olga-K54C NetworkManager[5191]: <info> (wlan0): supplicant interface state: 4-way handshake -> completed
Feb 11 18:09:20 olga-K54C NetworkManager[5191]: <info> Activation (wlan0/wireless) Stage 2 of 5 (Device Configure) successful.  Connected to wireless network 'corpse'.
Feb 11 18:09:20 olga-K54C NetworkManager[5191]: <info> Activation (wlan0) Stage 3 of 5 (IP Configure Start) scheduled.
Feb 11 18:09:20 olga-K54C NetworkManager[5191]: <info> Activation (wlan0) Stage 3 of 5 (IP Configure Start) started...
Feb 11 18:09:20 olga-K54C NetworkManager[5191]: <info> (wlan0): device state change: config -> ip-config (reason 'none') [50 70 0]
Feb 11 18:09:20 olga-K54C NetworkManager[5191]: <info> Activation (wlan0) Beginning DHCPv4 transaction (timeout in 45 seconds)
Feb 11 18:09:20 olga-K54C NetworkManager[5191]: <info> dhclient started with pid 5806
Feb 11 18:09:20 olga-K54C NetworkManager[5191]: <info> Activation (wlan0) Beginning IP6 addrconf.
Feb 11 18:09:20 olga-K54C NetworkManager[5191]: <info> Activation (wlan0) Stage 3 of 5 (IP Configure Start) complete.
Feb 11 18:09:20 olga-K54C dhclient: Internet Systems Consortium DHCP Client 4.1.1-P1
Feb 11 18:09:20 olga-K54C dhclient: Copyright 2004-2010 Internet Systems Consortium.
Feb 11 18:09:20 olga-K54C dhclient: All rights reserved.
Feb 11 18:09:20 olga-K54C dhclient: For info, please visit https://www.isc.org/software/dhcp/
Feb 11 18:09:20 olga-K54C dhclient: 
Feb 11 18:09:20 olga-K54C kernel: [ 3178.319668] wlan0: IPv6 duplicate address fe80::e6d5:3dff:fe58:6cd detected!
Feb 11 18:09:20 olga-K54C NetworkManager[5191]: <info> (wlan0): DHCPv4 state changed nbi -> preinit
Feb 11 18:09:20 olga-K54C dhclient: Listening on LPF/wlan0/e4:d5:3d:58:06:cd
Feb 11 18:09:20 olga-K54C dhclient: Sending on   LPF/wlan0/e4:d5:3d:58:06:cd
Feb 11 18:09:20 olga-K54C dhclient: Sending on   Socket/fallback
Feb 11 18:09:20 olga-K54C dhclient: DHCPDISCOVER on wlan0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 3
Feb 11 18:09:22 olga-K54C dhclient: DHCPDISCOVER on wlan0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 8
Feb 11 18:09:31 olga-K54C dhclient: DHCPDISCOVER on wlan0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 8
Feb 11 18:09:39 olga-K54C dhclient: DHCPDISCOVER on wlan0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 13
Feb 11 18:09:40 olga-K54C NetworkManager[5191]: <info> (wlan0): IP6 addrconf timed out or failed.
F    eb 11 18:09:40 olga-K54C NetworkManager[5191]: <info> Activation (wlan0) Stage 4 of 5 (IP6 Configure Timeout) scheduled...
Feb 11 18:09:40 olga-K54C NetworkManager[5191]: <info> Activation (wlan0) Stage 4 of 5 (IP6 Configure Timeout) started...
Feb 11 18:09:40 olga-K54C NetworkManager[5191]: <info> Activation (wlan0) Stage 5 of 5 (IP Configure Commit) started...
Feb 11 18:09:40 olga-K54C NetworkManager[5191]: <info> Activation (wlan0) Stage 5 of 5 (IP Configure Commit) failed (no IP configuration found)
Feb 11 18:09:40 olga-K54C NetworkManager[5191]: <info> (wlan0): device state change: ip-config -> failed (reason 'ip-config-unavailable') [70 120 5]
Feb 11 18:09:40 olga-K54C NetworkManager[5191]: <warn> Activation (wlan0) failed for access point (corpse)
Feb 11 18:09:40 olga-K54C NetworkManager[5191]: <info> Marking connection 'corpse' invalid.
Feb 11 18:09:40 olga-K54C NetworkManager[5191]: <warn> Activation (wlan0) failed.
Feb 11 18:09:40 olga-K54C NetworkManager[5191]: <info> Activation (wlan0) Stage 5 of 5 (IP Configure Commit) complete.
Feb 11 18:09:40 olga-K54C NetworkManager[5191]: <info> Activation (wlan0) Stage 4 of 5 (IP6 Configure Timeout) complete.
Feb 11 18:09:40 olga-K54C NetworkManager[5191]: <info> (wlan0): device state change: failed -> disconnected (reason 'none') [120 30 0]
Feb 11 18:09:40 olga-K54C NetworkManager[5191]: <info> (wlan0): deactivating device (reason 'none') [0]
Feb 11 18:09:40 olga-K54C NetworkManager[5191]: <info> (wlan0): canceled DHCP transaction, DHCP client pid 5806
Feb 11 18:09:40 olga-K54C kernel: [ 3198.359131] wlan0: deauthenticating from 14:da:e9:ba:ba:a4 by local choice (reason=3)
Feb 11 18:09:40 olga-K54C kernel: [ 3198.411144] cfg80211: All devices are disconnected, going to restore regulatory settings
Feb 11 18:09:40 olga-K54C kernel: [ 3198.411158] cfg80211: Restoring regulatory settings
Feb 11 18:09:40 olga-K54C kernel: [ 3198.411179] cfg80211: Calling CRDA to update world regulatory domain
Feb 11 18:09:40 olga-K54C wpa_supplicant[902]: CTRL-EVENT-DISCONNECTED bssid=00:00:00:00:00:00 reason=3
Feb 11 18:09:40 olga-K54C NetworkManager[5191]: <info> Policy set 'Wired connection 1' (eth0) as default for IPv4 routing and DNS.
Feb 11 18:09:40 olga-K54C NetworkManager[5191]: <info> Policy set 'Wired connection 1' (eth0) as default for IPv4 routing and DNS.
Feb 11 18:09:40 olga-K54C kernel: [ 3198.421270] cfg80211: Ignoring regulatory request Set by core since the driver uses its own custom regulatory domain 
Feb 11 18:09:40 olga-K54C kernel: [ 3198.421280] cfg80211: World regulatory domain updated:
Feb 11 18:09:40 olga-K54C kernel: [ 3198.421284] cfg80211:     (start_freq - end_freq @ bandwidth), (max_antenna_gain, max_eirp)
Feb 11 18:09:40 olga-K54C kernel: [ 3198.421292] cfg80211:     (2402000 KHz - 2472000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
Feb 11 18:09:40 olga-K54C kernel: [ 3198.421299] cfg80211:     (2457000 KHz - 2482000 KHz @ 20000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
Feb 11 18:09:40 olga-K54C kernel: [ 3198.421305] cfg80211:     (2474000 KHz - 2494000 KHz @ 20000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
Feb 11 18:09:40 olga-K54C kernel: [ 3198.421311] cfg80211:     (5170000 KHz - 5250000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
Feb 11 18:09:40 olga-K54C kernel: [ 3198.421317] cfg80211:     (5735000 KHz - 5835000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
Feb 11 18:09:40 olga-K54C NetworkManager[5191]: <info> (wlan0): supplicant interface state: completed -> disconnected
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try a hard reset.
There a small hole somewhere on the router.
Press it with a pen, etc. for 30 seconds (with power on).
Then log in to the router (192.168.0.1) and check/adjust your settings as desired.

Comment: Yes. The router turned out to be the problem. I tried resetting it few times. But it was glitching after some time anyway. So what solved my problem was firmware upgrade. If it helps someone else: the router is Asus RT-G32.C1 and the firmware can be found at [asus support site](http://support.asus.com/Download.aspx?SLanguage=en&p=11&m=RT-G32%20(VER.C1)&os=8)